# How to make an existing Android app implement a master-detail layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, master-detail

So I've built an application where you enter a bunch of information, click a button and it opens a new activity that graphs all the results.

I would like the interface and graph activities to be side-by-side on tablet devices, e.g. master-detail layout.

I've been through all the tutorials and understand it has something to do with Fragments, but don't need the tutorials lists or RecyclerView type approaches.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Reading more tutorials on lists and RecyclerView's isn't helping :(

Comment: sometimes the best way is to jump in middle and see what happens! start to use it in your code and monitor changes and its effect on UI, etc.

Comment: The important part about it is that you can use different layout configurations to show different ViewGroups (containers) on the page, into which you can put different fragments. Although in my experience, [master-detail + fragments is tricky](https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/blob/caf4579b7994f0dee3b4d2153265c5c91a71b3f2/simple-stack-flow-masterdetail-fragments/src/main/java/com/example/stackmasterdetailfrag/MasterDetailFragmentStateChanger.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is the following:

For your main activity with the button, you create a normal layout and another layout (with the same name) in layout-sw600dp-land.  This second layout should contain two layouts, the left layout should include all the components from the normal activity and the right side should have an empty layout that you will evenutally put a fragment into.

In your main activity's onCreate(), you can do a findviewbyid on the right hand layout and if it's not null, you know you are in the "landscape tablet mode".  For this case (right hand layout not null) when the button is pressed, you can use the fragment manager to add a fragment to that right hand layout - if not, you do what you are currently doing and launch another activity.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to combine your answer with a basic fragment example to get it working! Here's my code if anyone else is in the same boat [link](https://github.com/imurnane/TabletTest4)

Answer (score 1):

You do need to use fragments so learning how to use fragments is a good place to start.

I searched github for you and found this Master-Detail sample, with a link to his blog where he explains it in detail.
https://github.com/lurbas/MaterialMasterDetail

Android Studio will also provide you with a master-detail template. Create a new project and when you get to the screen that says "Add an Activity to Mobile," select the "Master/Detail Flow" activity. Study this bit of code and understand what it is doing.